# Add side bar in custom layout in magento2?

Tags: layout, magento2.3, php-7.2

I want to display the subcategory and product tabs in category page .So i have customise the layout file .

How to do this..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Added following code inside content container:

```
<container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
    <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
</container>
<container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
    <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
</container>
```

Comment: But i want to display 2columns-left  within a tab section

Comment: Maybe you need to add sidebar container inside product tab

Comment: yes ... how to do that

Comment: i want  to display page should be 1column

Comment: check updated answer. This is working fine with M2.3